# EE cuts the content of a big field

Tags: custom-fields, html

We have a text field were we want to put quite big HTML content (955 lines). We were able to do it without problem a few weeks ago, but now it's cutting the content, apparently always at the same point (around 65.000 characters).

EE let's you copy all the content, but when you save the page, it cuts it.

We haven't changed anything in our EE installation lately, but we made some changes to our PHP configuration for other reasons (so I guess it could be PHP related, but we are not sure and don't know how to fix it).

We've tried "pasting into the field and selecting another field", as suggested in https://expressionengine.com/forums/archive/topic/229708/problems-cutting-pasting-to-textarea-channel-fields, without luck. I haven't found more articles regarding this problem.

We are using version 2.10.1 - Build Date: 20150501.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check your field settings for any character limits. Specifically check that the field Maxlength, Default Text Formatting, and Field Content settings are appropriate to what you need. I've had several cases where I incorrectly set integer content or number content and then found my data was getting truncated.

If those are set correctly, you may need to open phpmyadmin or your database admin tool and check directly that your table/field settings are not limiting how many characters can be placed into the field in question.

And if those above items are correct, then I'd start looking for field input restrictions in modules/extensions (if you are using one for this input) that may be present. I suspect that since you have a very large amount of content to place into a single field, you may be running into a system level restriction on how much content can be written into a single field.

Finally, since you mentioned a recent change to php - have you looked at your php.ini file to check the upload settings?  Check your post_max_size settings in php.ini